# How do I 'subtract' sql tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Its not really a subtraction I'm looking for.  And I know its not a union or intersection...  I have been given a long and complex stored procedure that returns a table of active and inactive documents.  I have also been given a similar stored procedure that returns another table that contains only the active documents.

How could I get a table of inactive documents using these two store procedures?

We are using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: What database, and what are the table(s) and columns?

Comment: The 'official' name for this type of `JOIN` is the `LEFT ANTI SEMI JOIN` (at least this is what SQL Server calls it in its execution plans, and who am I to argue with a machine?) This is performed by looping over all the rows in one set, and discounting those from the other set that match on the specified criteria.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The set operation you are looking for is called MINUS, but in SQL Server the keyword is EXCEPT

```
  SELECT ... // all documents
  EXCEPT
  SELECT ... // active documents
```

I believe that the EXCEPT set operation became available in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: This is the right answer with respect to the underlying set operation.

Comment: Does that exist on Sql Server ?

Comment: Not in SQL Server. "It depends"

Comment: In SQL Server, the equivalent of MINUS is called EXCEPT

Answer (score 15):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 on Table1.id = Table2.id
WHERE Table2.id IS NULL
```

this should work on almost any database engine

Comment: I up-voted this answer because the `where Table2.id IS NULL` is exactly what makes it return the inverse. It was counter intuitive for me to write WHERE Table2.id `IS NULL` because neither of my columns could be `NULL`... but! that's the magic. Thank you for this, mate.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming there are unique IDs that correspond across the two tables:

```
select * from table_both b
where not exists (select * from table_active a where a.id = b.id)
```

Answer (score 9):

All good answers, but missing one point: The questioner (OP) has stored procedures...

You have to define temporary tables (based on your platform) to load the data

```
INSERT ...
EXEC getActive

INSERT ...
EXEC getInactive
```

*Then* use EXCEPT/EXISTS/MINUS/IN/OUTER JOIN/etc...

Answer (score 4):

```
select * from MyTable1
where MyTable1.Field1 not in (
  select Field1 from MyTable2)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe EXCEPT is what you are looking for.  Syntax is similar to UNION or INTERSECT.

Answer (score 3):

What's your DB engine?

In Oracle, you could use [MINUS](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Minus) set operation.

In MS SQLServer 2005 and newer you can use [EXCEPT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT both.*
FROM both LEFT OTUER JOIN inactives USING (whatever_id)
WHERE inactives.whatever_id IS NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM both
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM inactives;
```

Answer (score 1):

In MS TSql, I think you want the EXCEPT keyword.

```
query1 EXCEPT query2
```

Which will return all rows found in the first query that are not also found in the second query.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with the `NOT IN` clause

For example, assuming the stored procedures have given you table variables called `@AllDocuments` and `@ActiveDocuments` and each document has an identifier column called `DocId`

```
SELECT * FROM @AllDocuments 
WHERE DocId NOT IN 
    (SELECT DocId FROM @ActiveDocuments)
```

Adapt this as appropriate to match your table / column names.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT roll_number FROM profile WHERE(catagory='Attest and Eat' or catagory='Live and Eat') and status='OK' EXCEPT SELECT roll_number from meal_status  WHERE date='29' AND month='1'
```

You can try this kind of command to subtract a table from another one.

Answer (score 0):

For doing the subtraction between three tables I have used the following query:

Basically I have three tables.. table 1, table 2, table 3.
Firstly I have done the subtraction of table 1 and table 2 and then done the subtraction between the the  result of previous query and table 3.

```
select v3.Material, ((v1.Qty-v2.Qty)-v3.Qty) as Quantity
  from table1 v1, table2 v2, table3 v3
 where (v1.Material=v2.Material
    and v1.Material=v3.Material
    and v2.Material=v3.Material)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just used the first sp that return the Active & Inactive and 
in WHERE cluse put condition for the document status =inactive, you wil get inactive document only.

Answer (score 0):

if you are substracting a percentage and updating a table use this

```
UPDATE `TABLENAME` SET `COLUMNNAME` = (50 / 100) * `COLUMNNAME`;
```

please note that the (50 / 100) is for 50%  so in this case this query will discount 50% from the total value of the row!