# SQL Trigger to Delete records in one table after insert on a different table

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that will delete identical records in different table when records are inserted into a table. Here is my code.

```
   Create trigger [dbo].[RemoveCheckedInItems]
   on [dbo].[UTShipOrderDetailUp]
   after insert
   as

   delete from UTShipOrderDetail where UTShipOrderDetail.InvoiceID = 
   [UTShipOrderDetailUp].[InvoiceID] and 
   UTShipOrderDetail.ItemID=UTShipOrderDetailUp.ItemID
```

This is for inventory check-in so the customer downloads from the UTShipOrderDetail table and all items that were checked-in will be uploaded to the UTShipOrderDetailUp table. I need to delete the duplicate record in the UTShipOrderDetail table when one is inserted into the UTShipOrderDetailUp table. I am used to programming in VFP and this statement would work in there but no such luck in SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint : `Exsists` , `IN`

Comment: You should be using the inserted virtual table. I have to say that something seems a bit off with your design here. You are moving data from one table to another to indicate the status of something. This would probably be much better suited as a status column in your column instead of keeping copies of the data like you are doing.

Comment: I agree but I did not write the program that inserts the data into the tables. 
 I am not very familiar with SQL so I will have to look at how to use the inserted virtual table.

Comment: The insert virtual is a temp table, which has the data that was inserted, you can use that to join to and perform your delete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove row that exists in another table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437677/how-to-remove-row-that-exists-in-another-table)

Comment: You don't REALLY need to use the inserted table since this is an after trigger.  Just reconcile the two tables with a normal query.  IN, EXISTS, JOIN, all would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to join to the INSERTED table:

```
Create trigger [dbo].[RemoveCheckedInItems]
   on [dbo].[UTShipOrderDetailUp]
   after insert
   as
   begin
   set nocount on
   delete u
   from UTShipOrderDetail u
        inner join inserted i on i.InvoiceID = u.invoiceID and i.ItemID = u.ItemID
   end
```