# TSql Trigger To Delete Rows from Table1 Upon Insert to Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've read and tried other posts/answers but am having a hard time getting this to work.  I feel like it should be pretty simple for an experienced SQL programmer, but for me I'm ready to ask for help.

When I insert a record into the `HistoricalWorkorders` table, I simply want to delete any records with the same `workorder #` in the `ActiveWorkorders` table.

I'm trying to accomplish this using a trigger on insert.

I started simple by using the following code to insert into `ActiveWorkorders` every time a record is inserted into `HistoricalWorkorders`.  That code works.

---

> **How** do I modify this query such that upon insert to the `HistoricalWorkorders` table, any records with the same `workorder #` within the `ActiveWorkorders` table get deleted?

---

On a seperate note, everyone says you can reference the inserted record simply by referencing `'inserted'`, but it doesn't work for me?  For example, shouldn't `inserted.workorder` return the `workorder` value being inserted to the table?

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[WOArchive] on [dbo].[HistoricalWorkOrders]
after update,insert
as
begin
insert into ActiveWorkorders
(Workorder,Grindcount,Status)
select i.workorder, i.grindcount, i.status
from HistoricalWorkorders t
inner join inserted i on t.workorder=i.workorder
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by referencing inserted doesn't work? I am wondering what you are trying to do because currently this will insert a new row to ActiveWorkorders every time a row is inserted or updated in HistoricalWorkOrders. Just going on the names something seems a little bit off there. It would be helpful if you could include ddl for these two tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Trigger to Delete records in one table after insert on a different table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44805770/sql-trigger-to-delete-records-in-one-table-after-insert-on-a-different-table)