# Ignore date list from CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

CTE gives a below result

```
    Name            | StartDateTime           |  EndDateTime        
--------------------+-------------------------+------------------------
Hair Massage        | 2014-02-15 09:00:00.000 | 2014-02-15 10:00:00.000
Hair Massage        | 2014-02-15 10:00:00.000 | 2014-02-15 11:00:00.000
(X)Hair Massage     | 2014-02-23 09:00:00.000 | 2014-02-23 10:00:00.000
(X)Hair Cut         | 2014-02-20 12:15:00.000 | 2014-02-20 13:00:00.000
Hair Cut            | 2014-03-07 11:30:00.000 | 2014-03-07 12:15:00.000
```

Also I have **Holidays**

```
    Id       | StartDateTime      |  EndDateTime        
-------------+--------------------+-------------------
    1        | 20140223 00:00:00  | 20140224 23:59:00
```

And **EventBooking**

```
    EventId  | StartDateTime           |  EndDateTime        
-------------+-------------------------+------------------------
    1        | 2014-02-20 12:15:00.000 | 2014-02-20 13:00:00.000
```

I want to remove the dates falls under `holidays and EventBooking` from my CTE.
I mean remove the `(X)` recods from my CTE

`RESULT=CTE- BookedSchedule-Holidays`

```
with HoliDaysCte2 as
(
select StartdateTime,EndDateTime from Holidays
union all
select StartdateTime,EndDateTime from EventBooking
)

SELECT
    Name, 
    StartDateTime, 
    EndDateTime

FROM CTE WHERE not exists (select 1
                from HoliDaysCte2 h
                where cast(a.RepeatEventDate as DATETIME) between 
                   cast(h.startdatetime as DATETIME) 
                   and cast(h.enddatetime as DATETIME)
               )
```

Here is my [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07698/44)

Comment: It seams that, since you don't have a Calender entity in your design, having queries with table-scans to gain the result you need, is inevitable. BTW Current tables need to be joined on Date fields, that means non-effective yet efficient solution.

Comment: Did you try my query? It returns exactly what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay Assuming this is your schema

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.StaffSchedule
(       ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
        Name Varchar(50),       
        StartdateTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
        EndDateTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.BookedSchedules
(       ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
        StaffId INT,        
        StartdateTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
        EndDateTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE dbo.Holidays
(       ID INT,
        StartdateTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
        EndDateTime DATETIME2 NOT NULL
);
INSERT dbo.StaffSchedule (Name, StartdateTime, EndDateTime)
VALUES 
    ('Hair Massage','2014-02-15 09:00:00.000','2014-02-15 10:00:00.000'),
    ('Hair Massage','2014-02-15 10:00:00.000','2014-02-15 11:00:00.000'),
    ('(X)Hair Massage','2014-02-23 09:00:00.000','2014-02-23 10:00:00.000'),
    ('(X)Hair Cut','2014-02-20 12:15:00.000','2014-02-20 13:00:00.000'),
    ('Hair Cut','2014-03-07 11:30:00.000','2014-03-07 12:15:00.000');


INSERT dbo.BookedSchedules (StaffId, StartdateTime, EndDateTime)
VALUES 
(1,'2014-02-20 12:15:00.000','2014-02-20 13:00:00.000');

INSERT dbo.Holidays (ID,StartdateTime, EndDateTime)
VALUES 
(1,'20140223 00:00:00','20140224 23:59:00');
```

Does this solves your issue?

```
select * from StaffSchedule SS
where 
not exists(
select * from NonBookingSlots NBS
where (dateadd(MICROSECOND,1,ss.StartdateTime) 
    between nbs.StartdateTime and nbs.EndDateTime) 
        or (dateadd(MICROSECOND,-1,ss.EndDateTime) 
    between nbs.StartdateTime and nbs.EndDateTime))
```

Comment: Missing the `Id=2` record. Shows only one record . CHeck this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07698/46

Comment: To avoid ties can't you just add a millisecond to the margin values?

select * from StaffSchedule SS
where 
not exists(select 1 from NonBookingSlots BS 
           where (ss.StartdateTime
      between dateadd(MILLISECOND,1,bs.StartdateTime) and dateadd(millisecond,-1,bs.EndDateTime)))

Comment: can you add it in fiddle and share the working link?

Comment: Never used sqlfiddle , let me know if any trouble http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7f8a/2/0

Comment: This query will fail when a booked schedule starts before and ends after a period in StaffSchedules or Holidays, e.g. change the 2nd BookedSchedule row in the fiddle to (1, '2014-02-24 14:31:00.000', '2014-02-24 15:14:00.000')

Answer (score 2):

ok try this,

> create one more cte,

```
,cte2 as
(
select * from @Holidays
union all
select BookingID,StartdateTime,EndDateTime from @EventBooking
)
```

> then as usual

```
AND not exists (select 1
                from cte2 h
                where cast(a.RepeatEventDate as date) between cast(h.startdatetime as date) and cast(h.enddatetime as date)
               )
```

> this one is latest (datetime conversion very confusing,i just started
>   from @Gordon query.

```
AND not exists (select 1
                from cte2 h
                where cast(DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, 0, StartTime), RepeatEventDate) as datetime) between cast(h.startdatetime as datetime) and cast(h.enddatetime as datetime)
               )
```

Comment: I want to remove the dates falls under holidays and EventBooking from my CTE, please check my sqlfiddle link

Comment: Looks good for Holidays. But for EventBooking you removed all the rows for the corresponding day. Please check this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4e115/6 I need to remove only rows mentioned in EventBooking.

Comment: @Billa sorry i didn't get you.which row is wrong or which row is omitted.compare only date or datetime both ?

Comment: I mean `(X)` marked records only should get removed. They falls under date and time as well. Check my records in question

Comment: to make it more efficient it is important to know your whole query.There will be only one CTE(CTE2).and your main query will be the final one outside CTE.

Answer (score 2):

> RESULT= CTE - BookedSchedule - Holidays

Will be equal to use set theories subtract operation, in sql server you may use [Except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373833/how-do-i-subtract-sql-tables) (Minus in Oracle).

```
   select  StaffId, StartdateTime,EndDateTime  from StaffSchedule -- CTE 
    except
    (select  StaffId, StartdateTime,EndDateTime  from BookedSchedules) -- BookedSchedule 
    except
    (select StaffSchedule.StaffId, StaffSchedule.StartdateTime , StaffSchedule.EndDateTime
    from StaffSchedule 
    inner join Holidays 
    on 
    cast(Holidays.StartdateTime As Date) = cast(StaffSchedule.StartdateTime As Date)
    and 
    cast(Holidays.EndDateTime As Date) = cast(StaffSchedule.EndDateTime As Date) 
    )                                                                    -- Holidays
    ;
```

[***Sqlfiddle demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7db35/2) 
If a multi-day holiday could be inserted, like:

```
INSERT dbo.Holidays (StartdateTime, EndDateTime)
VALUES 
    ('2014-03-05 00:00:00.000', '2014-03-07 23:59:00.000');
```

Using the query bellow to extract staff-holidays will be useful:

```
(select StaffSchedule.StaffId, StaffSchedule.StartdateTime , StaffSchedule.EndDateTime
from StaffSchedule 
inner join Holidays 
on 
cast(Holidays.StartdateTime As Date) <= cast(StaffSchedule.StartdateTime As Date)
and 
cast(Holidays.EndDateTime As Date) >= cast(StaffSchedule.EndDateTime As Date) 
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
select * From StaffSchedule 
where ID not in(
        select 
            ID   
        From StaffSchedule a inner join 
        (
            select StartdateTime, EndDateTime From dbo.BookedSchedules
            union all
            select StartdateTime, EndDateTime From dbo.Holidays
        )b  on a.StartdateTime between b.StartdateTime and b.EndDateTime and 
            a.EndDateTime between b.StartdateTime and b.EndDateTime)
```

Chekck [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07698/94)

Answer (score 1):

This will surely help you.....

```
WITH CTE AS (
            SELECT 
                S.ID,
                S.StaffId ,
                S.StartdateTime,
                S.EndDateTime,
                H.StartdateTime 'HolydayStartDate' ,
                H.EndDateTime AS 'HolydayDateDate',
                B.StartdateTime AS 'BookedStartDate',
                B.EndDateTime AS 'BookedEndDate'
            FROM @StaffSchedule S 
                 LEFT JOIN @Holidays H   ON S.StartdateTime >= H.StartdateTime AND S.EndDateTime <= H.EndDateTime 
                 LEFT JOIN @BookedSchedules B ON B.StaffId = S.StaffId AND B.StartdateTime = S.StartdateTime AND B.EndDateTime = S.EndDateTime
         )
         SELECT * FROM CTE 
         WHERE 
                HolydayStartDate IS NULL AND 
                HolydayDateDate  IS NULL AND 
                BookedStartDate  IS NULL AND 
                BookedEndDate  IS NULL
```

Comment: @billa ask me is there any problems in my query.

Comment: Can you edit the fiddle link i gave and check it by yourself whether your code is working or not?

Answer (score 1):

To check for overlapping periods you need to do:

```
where p1.StartdateTime < p2.enddatetime
  and p1.enddatetime > p2.startdatetime
```

Depending on your needs it might be >=/<= instead of >/<.

Based on your fiddle:

```
with NonBookingSlots as
(
select StartdateTime,EndDateTime from Holidays
union all
select StartdateTime,EndDateTime from BookedSchedules
)

SELECT
    *
FROM StaffSchedule as ss
WHERE StaffId=1 

AND not exists (select *
                from NonBookingSlots h
                where h.StartdateTime < ss.enddatetime
                  and h.enddatetime > ss.startdatetime
               )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you -

```
SELECT ss.* FROM StaffSchedule ss
LEFT JOIN BookedSchedules bs 
    ON (ss.StartdateTime BETWEEN bs.StartdateTime AND bs.EndDateTime) 
    AND (ss.EndDateTime BETWEEN bs.StartdateTime AND bs.EndDateTime)
LEFT JOIN Holidays h 
    ON (ss.StartdateTime BETWEEN h.StartdateTime AND h.EndDateTime) 
    AND (ss.EndDateTime BETWEEN h.StartdateTime AND h.EndDateTime)
WHERE bs.ID IS NULL AND h.StartdateTime IS NULL AND h.EndDateTime IS NULL
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01301/3)